# Strategies to Implement search on XML file

Tags: html, xml

I have found some posts related to search on XML but those were not helpful for my task.

My task is to implement a search. 
Source: 5-6 XML files like People,Buildings,News etc (each category being an XML file I have 30000 Entries totally). 
User can select a category and type some keyword. The search phrase should search the XML file and return results are to presented on a html page. If user doesn't select a category all XML files should be searched.

Please tell me best strategy/Algorithm to implement this and best technology.

Comment: Which is the schema of the XMLs? A lot of languages let you parse and search XML: which are your constraints? What kind of solution are you seeking? Web app? Stand alone? Console batch? Which kind of environment will host the solution? Why aren't that posts helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform your XML documents (using XSL) and upload them (HTTP post) to an instance of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). You'll then be able to perform a range of search operations on the indexed data.

The [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) is unavailable currently, but here's an example of it's support XML format:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
    <field name="office">Bridgewater</field>
    <field name="skills">Perl</field>
    <field name="skills">Java</field>
  </doc>
  [<doc> ... </doc>[<doc> ... </doc>]]
</add>
```